# How to use Group By with AND in java codes

Tags: sql, eclipse

Trying to get values from my table but having problem with my snytaxes

there is wrong type with "Group By" usage with "AND" 
any help will be apriciated

```
"SELECT " + C_CINSIYET + " FROM " + TABLE_COMPANYS + " WHERE "
                    + C_MARKA + " = '" + companyMarka.getComp_marka() + "'"
                    + " AND " + C_FIRMA + " = '"
                    + companyMarka.getComp_name() + "' GROUP BY "
                    + C_CINSIYET + "AND"+C_FIRMA;
```

Comment: The separator in `group by` is `,`, not `and`.

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask a new question; don't re-purpose an old one.

Comment: Hello ams , I have reached my asking limit dont have any permission to ask new ones.